# how to calculate the number of lines separating 2 occurrences of the same keyword in a text file in python?

Tags: python, string, text, line

I have a python **scraping** script to get infos about some upcomming concerts and it's the same text pattern everytime no matter how many concerts will appear, the only difference is that sometimes it will show an additional line with the price of the tickets when they are still available to book such as the example below:

```
LIVE 01/01/99 9PM
Iron Maiden
Madison Square Garden 
New York City
LIVE 01/01/99 9.30PM
The Doors
Staples Center
Los Angeles
LIVE 01/02/99 8.45PM
Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg
Staples Center
Los Angeles
Book a ticket now for $99,99
LIVE 01/02/99 9PM
Diana Ross
City Hall
New York City 
Book a ticket now for $79,99       ect...
```

I need to calculate the number of lines for each text block and check if it's a 4 or a 5 block lines, so what I was thinking was to calculate the occurrence of the 1st word of each block ("LIVE") and then add an if statement to sort blocks between the 2 categories (4 lines blocks & 5 lines blocks)

The if statement part isn't difficult but I simply don't know how to do the first part, maybe a readlines then when a line has the keyword "LIVE", add the lines position (with the data sample provided that would be line 1, line 5, line 9, line 14, here we can clearly see that the first 2 blocks are 4 lines but the 3rd one is 5 lines) and then if statement part to sort them out

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT with my idea of code, I hope it will be clearer like that I need to get the code for the variables line_number and gap_each_line:

```
with open('concerts_list.txt', 'r') as file:          
    reading_file = file.read()
    lines = reading_file.split('\n')
    for "LIVE" in lines:
        line_number = #the part where I'm stuck to tell each line number
 where the word "LIVE" appears. output desired: [0, 4, 8, 13]
        gap_each_line = #calculate the gap between each number of previous 
variable line_number. output desired: [4, 4, 5]
    if gap == 4 for gap in gap_each_line:
        dates = [i for i in lines [0::4]]
    elif gap == 5 for gap in gap_each_line:
        dates = [i for i in lines [0::5]]
```

Comment: How your expected output looks like ?

Comment: I have actually assigned a variable to each data (date, band,location ect..) so when I iterate between the lines I'm doing that: dates = [i for i in lines [0::4]]. So after getting the line number I'll be able to fo my if statement and then assign 2 categories, dates = [i for i in lines [0::4]] & dates = [i for i in lines [0::5]]

Comment: So your final output will be a table with column header as date, band, location, price etc. Am I right ?

Comment: I just edited my initial post to be clearer with some code idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read_csv of pandas` module.

I hope your entire problem (finding date etc) can be solved using `pandas`.

Below is the code to find the line differences between lines starts with 'LIVE'

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/prince/Downloads/test3.csv', sep='~~~', header=None, engine='python')
df.columns = ['Details']
df['si_no'] = df['Details'].str.startswith('LIVE').cumsum()
gaps = df.groupby('si_no').apply(lambda x : len(x)).values
print(gaps)
```

it will print

```
[4 4 5 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you provided your desired output (Prince Francis answer), but I get the feeling you're trying to solve something on a difficult way.

Please have a look at this:

```
from collections import defaultdict #Defaultdict let's you create a dictionary, which is already set up to contain a list for every key

concerts = defaultdict(list)
current_dictKey = None # Starts "unset"
with open('/tmp/concerts_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    reading_file = file.read()
    lines = reading_file.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        print('I just read the following:', line)
        if line.startswith('LIVE'):
            print('The current line starts with keyword "live", so this will be the dictionarys new Key')
            current_dictKey = line
            continue # Continue to next line without doing anything else

        if line.startswith('Book a ticket'):
            print("This line starts with 'book a ticket'. Let's skip those too.")
            continue # Skip those lines. I guess you don't want them either.

        concerts[current_dictKey].append(line) # Just add the line to the Key in defaultdict


print()
print('This is the object "concerts"you get as the result:')
print(concerts)
print()


print('You can access a specific value like this:', concerts['LIVE 01/01/99 9PM'])
```

Once it's in the Dictionary, you can access all your data very easily.

Comment: I only need the code for these 2 variables because the part of my code after that where I access values in my dates, band, location ect... variables is working perfecly, so I really just need to check the number of lines in each block and then sort them out to their respective 4 or 5 lines categories

Answer (score 0):

(I created a new answer, because i still think my first one suits most situations better.)

This creates your desired output:

```
live_lines = []
line_counter = 0
distances = []
with open('concerts_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    reading_file = file.read()
    lines = reading_file.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('LIVE'):
            live_lines.append(line_counter)

        line_counter += 1

for position in range(len(live_lines)-1):
    new_distance = live_lines[position+1] - live_lines[position]
    distances.append(new_distance)

print('live_lines:', live_lines)
print('distances', distances)
```

Output:

```
live_lines: [0, 4, 8, 13]
Distances [4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: that's working perfectly thanks! But that's only the first part of my issue, now the idea is to calculate the gap between each block and get the result into the variable gap_each_line. Then finally sort the 4 and 5 blocks out inside their respective categories in order to access properly the data (dates, bands ect...)

Comment: I just edited my post and added the distance-calculation.

This iterates through the live_lines array (except the last one) and makes a simple substraction.

Comment: thanks a lot again Alex it worked like a charm! Sorry to push a little bit further (last time for sure haha) but for the last part where I added my if statement to sort out blocks and access my data according to each category isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you wrote but written in more pythonic style.

```py
with open('concerts_list.txt', 'rt') as file:
    indices = [index for index, line in enumerate(file) if line.startswith("LIVE")]
    block_lengths = [adjacent - current for current, adjacent in zip(indices , indices [1:])]
```

If your file is really big you can use [generator comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to lazy load only the data you need in memory for calculation. So comparing to first example here you work with stream of data using [Iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) object instead of a in-memory list.

```py
import itertools

with open('concerts_list.txt', 'rt') as file:
    # generator comprehension
    indices = (index for index, line in enumerate(file) if line.startswith("LIVE"))
    # itertools.tee make copies of iterators
    indices_1, indices_2 = itertools.tee(indices)
    # here itertools.islice make new iterator without first element
    block_lengths = [adjacent - current for current, adjacent in
                     zip(indices_1, itertools.islice(indices_2, 1, None))]
```